# How can you make a % wildcard make rule phony?

Tags: makefile, wildcard, gnu-make

I have the following wildcard "programming" make rule that uploads a binary to a device. This obviously does not produce a real file, so should be marked phony. However, how do you mark a % percent wildcard rule phony?

```
%-tangnano-prog: %-tangnano.fs
    openFPGALoader -b tangnano $^

.PHONY: %-tangnano-prog clean all
```

The phony rule does not give any error whatever you put there, so hard to tell if it worked. But I believe it did not:

```sh
$ touch blinky-tangnano-prog
$ make blinky-tangnano-prog
make: 'blinky-tangnano-prog' is up to date.
```

Answer (score 4):

Thee are basically two possibilities:

1. You know in advance what `%-tangnano-prog` targets you can encounter. Just assign all their prefixes to a make variable, use make functions to compute the full target names and declare them as phony:

   ```
    P := blinky foo bar
    T := $(addsuffix -tangnano-prog,$(P))

    .PHONY: tangnano-prog $(T)

    tangnano-prog: $(T)

    %-tangnano-prog: %-tangnano.fs
        openFPGALoader -b tangnano $^
   ```
2. You do not know in advance what targets you can encounter. Use the same Makefile but pass the list of target prefixes to build on the command line:

   ```
    $ make tangnano-prog P="blinky foo bar"
   ```

Comment: Another option for #2: add this: `.PHONY: $(filter-out %-tangnano-prog,$(MAKECMDGOALS))`

Comment: @MadScientist Nice but shouldn't it be `filter` instead of `filter-out`?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry I typed too fast :)

Comment: Oh I like the mad scientist option!

Comment: Oh, yes! The MadScientist option should be the real answer!